# JPQL query ignores hibernate @Type annotation

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

I'm persisting org.joda.Money in my db. For this purpose I'm using custom hibernate Type (defined similar to jadira Type - I copied the implementation and changed some properties). Money object is saved in 2 separate columns. Everything works correctly (native queries + saving entity class via `repository.save(MyEntity entity)` method), but JPQL queries cannot handle this column - it looks like type annotation is ignored. When I'm trying to update entity with Money object I'm getting error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ","
  Position: 56
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:130)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
```

When I printed sql I saw:
Hibernate: update my_entity set money_currency, money_amount=(?, ?) where id=?

So for some reason it is trying to put 2 values into 1 column.

My configuration:

```java
public class MyEntity {
  
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Columns(columns = {@Column(name = "money_currency"), @Column(name = "money_amount")})
  @Type(type = "org.project.utils.PersistentMoneyAmountAndCurrency")
  private Money money;
}
```

Custom type:

```java
import org.jadira.usertype.moneyandcurrency.legacyjdk.columnmapper.BigDecimalBigDecimalColumnMapper;
import org.jadira.usertype.spi.shared.AbstractMultiColumnUserType;
import org.jadira.usertype.spi.shared.ColumnMapper;
import org.joda.money.CurrencyUnit;
import org.joda.money.Money;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class PersistentMoneyAmountAndCurrency extends AbstractMultiColumnUserType<Money> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3735995469031558183L;
    private static final ColumnMapper<?, ?>[] COLUMN_MAPPERS = new ColumnMapper[]{new StringColumnCurrencyUnitMapper(), new BigDecimalBigDecimalColumnMapper()};
    private static final String[] PROPERTY_NAMES = new String[]{"currencyUnit", "amount"};

    public PersistentMoneyAmountAndCurrency() {
    }

    @Override
    protected ColumnMapper<?, ?>[] getColumnMappers() {
        return COLUMN_MAPPERS;
    }

    @Override
    protected Money fromConvertedColumns(Object[] convertedColumns) {
        CurrencyUnit currencyUnitPart = (CurrencyUnit) convertedColumns[0];
        BigDecimal amountPart = (BigDecimal) convertedColumns[1];
        final BigDecimal bigDecimal = amountPart.movePointRight(currencyUnitPart.getDecimalPlaces());
        return Money.ofMinor(currencyUnitPart, bigDecimal.longValue());
    }

    @Override
    protected Object[] toConvertedColumns(Money value) {
        return new Object[]{value.getCurrencyUnit(), value.getAmount()};
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getPropertyNames() {
        return PROPERTY_NAMES;
    }
}
```

JPQL Query:

```java
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "update MyEntity me set " +
               "me.money = :money, " +
               "where me.id = :id ")
    int updateMoney(Long id, Money money);
```

EntityManager configuration (for my project purpose I have to create it manually):

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManager",
                       transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager",
                       basePackages = {"org"})
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    private final DatabaseProperties databaseProperties;

    @Bean("dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName(databaseProperties.getJpa().getDriver());
        config.setJdbcUrl(databaseProperties.getUrl());
        config.setUsername(databaseProperties.getUsername());
        config.setPassword(databaseProperties.getPassword());
        config.addDataSourceProperty("poolName", "jdbc-accountant-pool");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("registerJmx", true);
        config.addDataSourceProperty("idleTimeout", databaseProperties.getJpa().getIdleTimeout());
        config.addDataSourceProperty("minimumIdle", databaseProperties.getJpa().getMinimumIdle());
        config.addDataSourceProperty("maximumPoolSize", databaseProperties.getJpa().getMaximumPoolSize());
        config.addDataSourceProperty("connectionTimeout", databaseProperties.getJpa().getConnectionTimeout());
        config.addDataSourceProperty("leakDetectionThreshold", databaseProperties.getJpa().getLeakDetectionThreshold());
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManager")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder.dataSource(getDataSource())
                      .properties(hibernateProperties())
                      .packages("org")
                      .build();
    }

    private Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties() {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("hibernate.properties");
        try {

            Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
            return properties.entrySet()
                             .stream()
                             .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey()
                                                             .toString(),
                                                       Map.Entry::getValue));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new HashMap<>();

        }
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager accountantTransactionManager(@Qualifier("entityManager") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

Do you see what may make this issue? Thanks for your ideas!